# BigQuery private key validation

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

We are integrating with Big query using Node js and we are initializing BigQuery client inline like below

```
const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery({ projectId: 'bigqueryproject1', credentials: { client_email: "dev1@account.com", private_key: " <-----abcd...------>" }, });
```

while testing we observed that even if we replace 2-3 characters from Valid key with some other Characters then we don't get any error, functionality works successfully. If we alter about 8 characters then we get Base64 related error. Please let us know if this is expected behavior.
Note : If we change Key format, i.e. removed leading and trailing "----" or add extra characters to the key then we get error. Do we need to validate key using Base64 format ?

Comment: In order to authenticate your API requests you have to provide set up a Service Account or provide a key.json file. Such as described in the documentation [link1](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-bigquery-nodejs/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file). Also can you elaborate more on what you mean by "validating key using Base64"?

Comment: Hi, I mean do i need to validate that key provided is of base64 format using some library or not.

Comment: If you downloaded the key.json from your service account, you do not need to validade it. You need just to use it as described in the links I shared above.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Google does not validate the key in combination to the email id. Let it be user's responsibility to add proper key

Comment: Thanks Cooldev, yes validating key will also be overhead